# How to Invoke Roman Family Font After Calling in the Baskervald Package?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, roman, default, cabin

It is my understanding that when one calls in the `basketvald` package, the Roman family default is changed to baskervald. Hence, one can call in the baskervald font with the command `\rmfamily`.

In the following MWE, I am also invoking `cabin`; and so, I call in this font with `\sffamily`---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{baskervald}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\sffamily
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{10pt}
\rmfamily
\lipsum[2]
\vspace{10pt}

% % How to display the next paragraph in "real" Roman font---
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which produces the three paragraphs:

[image]

QUESTION: Now that the default `rmfamily` font has been set to baskervald, how may I display the third paragraph in the ``real'' Roman family (original default) font?

Thank you.

Comment: CMR is not a more 'real' serif family ;). It's just the default in TeX. (Depending on your engine and packages, it might not even be the default, though you'd likely get LMR instead.) The true original serif family is lost to the annals of time ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (temporarily) renew Computer Modern Roman (cmr) as the `\rmdefault` and then invoke it, via `\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}\rmfamily`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{baskervald}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{10pt}
\rmfamily
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{10pt}
% % How to display the next paragraph in "real" Roman font---
{\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}\rmfamily
\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Computer Modern Roman multiple times --- rather than just as a one off --- you may prefer to define commands analogous to the default font-changing commands. For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cmrfamily}{%
  \fontfamily{cmr}%
  \selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcmr}{\cmrfamily}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\sffamily
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{10pt}
\rmfamily
\lipsum[2]
\vspace{10pt}

Hello! \textcmr{Hello!}

% % How to display the next paragraph in "real" Roman font---
\cmrfamily
\lipsum[2]

\rmfamily
Back to Baskervald.
\end{document}
```

[image: Cabin, Baskervald and CMR]

*However*, please do consider whether you really need to do this. Unless you have some specific reason for doing this, a document with this mixture of fonts will be the poorer for it. Too many different fonts do not make for good typography.

Of course, if you're typesetting a book of font samples or writing an article about the differences between Cabin, Baskervald and CMR, say, that's obviously very different. But otherwise, please consider the wisdom of using what you wished for!

Answer (score 0):

There is no “real” font. However, LaTeX provides Computer Modern as the default font if the user (or the document class) doesn't choose differently, because not providing one would make empty documents (TeX *does* have a default font called `\nullfont` that has no character).

It's common knowledge that the default Roman font family has symbolic name `cmr` and the default sans serif family is `cmss`. But you don't even need to know it: just save them before choosing new fonts.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% save the default family name before changing it
\NewCommandCopy{\rmstandard}{\rmdefault}
\NewCommandCopy{\sfstandard}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{baskervald}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\stdrmfamily}{}{\fontfamily{\rmstandard}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textstdrm}{\stdrmfamily}
\NewDocumentCommand{\stdsffamily}{}{\fontfamily{\sfstandard}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textstdsf}{\stdsffamily}

\begin{document}

Abc\textsf{Abc}\textstdrm{Abc}\textstdsf{Abc}

\vspace{10pt}

\sffamily
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\vspace{10pt}

\rmfamily
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\vspace{10pt}

\stdrmfamily
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\vspace{10pt}

\stdsffamily
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]